# C# - Instantiate an object A where its constructor takes in parameter an object B that needs the reference of A (like One-to-One relationship)

Tags: c#

I have a class A and B like this :

```
public class B {

    private A myA { get; }

    public B(A a) {
        myA = a;
    }
}

public class A {

    private B myB { get; }

    public A(B b) {
        myB = b;
    }
}
```

I would like to know if it is possible, in one instruction, to instantiate an A and a B at the same time without having to use

```
B b = new B();
A a = new A(b);
b.SetA();
```

or

```
A a = null;
a = new A(new B(a));
```

The reason I want to be able to do this in one instruction is because I want to be able to instatiate a class of type A in the constructor of another class like this

```
public abstract class SuperClass() {

    private A myA { get; }

    public SuperClass(A a) {
        myA = a;
    }
}

public class SpecificClassWithKnownValuesOfA() : SuperClass {

    public SpecificClassWithKnownValuesOfA() : base(/* here I want to use new A(new B(ref of a)) */) { }
}
```

Note that B.myA and A.myB are readonly properties as I don't want to put setters

Comment: No, you can't. You have an AB problem. Er, XY problem. Why do you want this? Change your design so you don't have a circular dependency, or make one of the dependencies a property that you assign after instantiating instead.

Comment: I really doubt `a = new A(new B(a));` would work.

Comment: `class B { public void B(A a) => myA = a;}` and `class A { public void A() => myB = new B(this);}` could work .. if you do not need to reference B outside of A. I would probably make B just a setter though... difficult to say without more knowledge about your design

Comment: What's the purpose of private autogenerated properties ?

Comment: I edited the question for more details

Answer (score 2):

I have to say that you can't do this. I understand that you want to prevent getting an `A` without `B`, and prevent getting a `B` without `A`.

I suggest using the factory pattern with a private constructor.

For A:

```cs
    public class A
    {
        private B _b;
        public A(B b)
        {
            _b = b;
        }
    }
```

For B, do not create a public constructor. Use a builder to build it, so every time you get a `B`, there is always a fine instance in it.

```cs
    public class B
    {
        private A _a;
        private B() { }

        public (A, B) Init()
        {
            var b = new B();
            _a = new A(b);
            return (_a, b);
        }
    }
```

To get it, call:

```cs
var (a, b) = B.Init();
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do this:

```
public class B {

    private A myA { get; public set; }

    public B() {}

    public B(A a) {
        myA = a;
        a.B = this;
    }
}

public class A {

    private B myB { get; public set; }

    public A(){}

    public A(B b) {
        myB = b;
        b.A = this;
    }
}


var a = new A(new B());
```

or alternatively

```
var b = new B(new A());
```

Whether its a good idea however is another question

Comment: I would like that attributs are readonly fields so b.A = this; and a.B = this; isn't correct

Comment: well the first thing to do is to make them fields, not properties.

Comment: sorry I meant properties

Answer (score 0):

You can like `this` :

```
public class B {

    // This should be public with eventually a private setter
    public A myA { get; private set; }    

    public B(A a) {
        myA = a;
    }
}

public class A {

    public B myB { get; private set; }

    public A() {
        myB = new B(this);
    }
}
```

And then

```
A a = new A();
```

Comment: Isn't this already addressed in the question? "*I would like to know if it is possible, in one instruction, to instantiate an A and a B at the same time **without having to use***"